# How in java throw again exception the same type?

Tags: java, exception, throw

I need to restore data on exception and after throw exception of the same type.
Is it possible if in compile time I don't know the type of exception?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
try
{
  // your code here.
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
  // your code here.
  throw exception;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details; is it a `RuntimeException`? If not, you're already catching it, just rethrow it. If there's no try/catch, you'd need to wrap it in one, and throw it.

If you don't have access to the code, you can use something like AspectJ.